# ¿En que parte de la estructura de mi pagina debería de poner los rich snippets? ¿quizás en el header del body?

Tags: html, estructuras-de-datos

Esta es mi página web https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/, este es mi codigo rich snippets que esta al final del body

```js
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "enviar mensaje masivo outlook office ",
  "description": "las personas lo reciben como que si estuviera destinado solo a ellos y no como una cadena,  cada persona verá su propia dirección de correo en el mensaje y no la del resto de contactos",
  "thumbnailUrl": [
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1LhkxeHZm0A/hqdefault.jpg"
   ],
  "uploadDate": "2017-10-23T19:57:00",
  "duration": "PPT4M28S",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LhkxeHZm0A",
  "interactionCount": "67"
}
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo pongo mi pagina en esta herramienta, y esta herramienta me identifica rich snippets https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=es

pero en el search console structured data report no es identificado el rich snippets https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data?authuser=1&visit_id=1-636524202939470307-1325668532&hl=es&rd=1 ver la imagen https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sDwVCoufVArOfxqmKZXdv5XM4kFIw_XC/view?usp=sharing ¿por qué aqui en el reporte no me identifica el rich snippets y en la herramienta anterior si? ¿Donde debo poner mi rich snippets o que debo de hacer para que me lo identifique? ¿Talvés deba ponerlo en el header así?:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Bienvenidos</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3473978549309154",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imagenes/ale2.jpg">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "enviar mensaje masivo outlook office ",
  "description": "las personas lo reciben como que si estuviera destinado solo a ellos y no como una cadena,  cada persona verá su propia dirección de correo en el mensaje y no la del resto de contactos",
  "thumbnailUrl": [
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1LhkxeHZm0A/hqdefault.jpg"
   ],
  "uploadDate": "2017-10-23T19:57:00",
  "duration": "PPT4M28S",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LhkxeHZm0A",
  "interactionCount": "67"
}
</script>
```